# ViewModel databinding backgroud color

Tags: android, mvvm, android-databinding, android-viewmodel

I want to display status of my app as a color of ConstraintLayout. My app is single activity and using MVVM.

```
private val _status = NonNullMutableLiveData(NacinDelaEnum.OFFLINE)
val status:LiveData<NacinDelaEnum>
        get()=_status
```

Depending on value of `status` I would like to color background of ConstraintLayout.

NacinDelaEnum is just a simple enum class

```
enum class NacinDelaEnum {
ONLINEEXT,ONLINEINT,OFFLINE
}
```

When user starts application I ping internally, then external and depending on that I change value of  `_status`.

In case of `OFFLINE` I would like background to be red, `ONLINEINT` green and `ONLINEEXT`blue.

I have tried

```
val back: LiveData<Int> = Transformations.switchMap(_status){
    someFunc(it)
}

private fun someFunc(status: NacinDelaEnum) =
    when(status){
    NacinDelaEnum.ONLINEINT->MutableLiveData(Color.GREEN)
    NacinDelaEnum.OFFLINE->MutableLiveData(Color.RED)
    NacinDelaEnum.ONLINEEXT->MutableLiveData(Color.GREEN)
}
```

And in xml

```
android:background="@{safeUnbox(viewModel.back)}"
```

I also have this properly imported since it works on another variable.

```
<variable name="viewModel" type="com.example.mjagrosk.viewmodels.SettingsViewModel"/>
```

I guess my transormation is not right. How could I make it?

Thanks

Comment: Are you calling something like `binding.setLifecycleOwner(this)` in your fragment?

Comment: Yes I am. As I said I have another LiveData bind to TextView and it works. I am almost sure the problem is in that Transformations.switchMap.

Answer (score 0):

What about using a BindingAdapter to apply your NacinDelaEnum directly to the view?

```
@BindingAdapter("nacinDela")
fun setBackground(view: View, nacinDela: NacinDelaEnum) {
    view.setBackgroundColor(view.context.getColor(getColorValue(nacinDela)))
}

fun getColorValue(nacinDela: NacinDelaEnum): Int {
    when(status){
        NacinDelaEnum.ONLINEINT-> MutableLiveData(Color.GREEN)
        NacinDelaEnum.OFFLINE->MutableLiveData(Color.RED)
        NacinDelaEnum.ONLINEEXT->MutableLiveData(Color.GREEN)
}
```